# WP - update user meta by user itself - troubles with saving

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have a basic question about Wordpress update_user_meta. I am trying to write a from, which can be edited by a user. The problem is, value from submitted form is saved in database, but after reload of the page is value removed from DB.

The code is:

```
<?php
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
 echo $user->schoolstudentscount;
 ?>
<form name="Students Count" action="" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<input type="text" id="count_of_students" name="count_of_students"/>
</fieldset>
<button type="submit">Save</button>
 </form>
<?php
$low_price = $_POST['count_of_students'];
update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'schoolstudentscount', $low_price); 
 ?>
```

Better explanation:

1. Simple form, where number 35 is taken from DB.
2. Value is changed to 25 and form is submited
3. Value 25 is stored in DB and shown in the value field
4. After F5 value disappears from input field and from database.

[image: SQL number taken from Database]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I understand well, I need to somehow redirect the page itself to store data in database without being erased.

Anyone knows how to write the program correctly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( isset( $_POST['count_of_students'] ) ){
    $low_price = $_POST['count_of_students'];
    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'schoolstudentscount', $low_price);
}
```

This will only update the user meta if the count_of_students is submitted/posted.